# how to implement Voucher payment with paypal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal, e-commerce

I have an asp.net mvc e-commerce application that requires voucher payment. how to pass the voucher amount/ How to set the discount amount on the entire cart? - to paypal that will be deducted from the total payable amount upon payment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer! the variable name is

```
discount_amount_cart
```

thank you @GolezTrol

Answer (score 1):

Just check the voucher on your own site, subtract the value, and only send the remaining amount to paypal.

Comment: right now i'm sending itemized price and quantity and paypal is calculating the total. How to send the total amount(variable name?)?

Comment: I thought you already sent the total. In your case, send an extra line with the negative voucher amount. This will count as a discount. (see also http://www.zen-cart.com/forum/showthread.php?p=715849 Even if you don't use Zen-cart, it still implies the possibility to send negative amounts).

Comment: this sounds a bit chiky way of doing this)). any better way that will display in paypal payment page the discount amount for the entire cart?

Comment: Apparently there is such thing as a discount variable. I don't know the details, but I found this document: https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_WebsitePaymentsStandard_IntegrationGuide.pdf Also, I found a thread that seems to issue the same question: https://www.x.com/thread/42938